# Reproducing toc format

Tags: table-of-contents, tcolorbox

In the `tcolorbox` manual we see the following toc format

[image]

I would like to reproduce it however I have no idea how to do it. I don't even know where to begin from. I am not familiar with the packages presented in the `tcolorbox` manual.

I would appreciate your  help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ToC` style presented in `tcolorbox` manual is written in `tcolorbox.doc.abtract.tex` which can be found in the documentation directory of `tcolorbox`, i.e. on my personal computer the path for TL 2017 is

> /usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tcolorbox

I've copied the code from there and wrapped a small document around it.

Basically, the settings are just `tcolorbox` 'standards', then use `\@starttoc{toc}` in order to load the contents of `\jobname.toc`, as is done basically in any `\tableofcontents` macro.

The file `goldshade.png` is shipped with the `tcolorbox` package

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{blindtext}


\begin{document}


\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable,enhanced jigsaw,title={Contents},fonttitle=\bfseries\Large,
  colback=yellow!10!white,colframe=red!50!black,before=\par\bigskip\noindent,
  interior style={fill overzoom image=goldshade.png,fill image opacity=0.25},
  colbacktitle=red!50!yellow!75!black,
  enlargepage flexible=\baselineskip,pad at break*=3mm,
  watermark color=yellow!75!red!25!white,
  watermark text={\bfseries\Large Contents},
  attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-0.25mm-\tcboxedtitleheight/2,yshifttext=2mm-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},
  boxed title style={enhanced,boxrule=0.5mm,
    frame code={ \path[tcb fill frame] ([xshift=-4mm]frame.west) -- (frame.north west)
    -- (frame.north east) -- ([xshift=4mm]frame.east)
    -- (frame.south east) -- (frame.south west) -- cycle; },
    interior code={ \path[tcb fill interior] ([xshift=-2mm]interior.west)
    -- (interior.north west) -- (interior.north east)
    -- ([xshift=2mm]interior.east) -- (interior.south east) -- (interior.south west)
    -- cycle;}  },
  drop fuzzy shadow]
\makeatletter
\@starttoc{toc}
\makeatother
\end{tcolorbox}

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Christian, any way to achieve the space in the toc that the image in my post shows? After some sections the number and the title of the section in toc gets add together .... !!