# Reproducing toc format [2] ( space problem )

Tags: table-of-contents

As a continuation to this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/406158/reproducing-toc-format/406160#406160) of mine I am having a problem with spaces in the toc. See attachment:

[image]

As you can see after subsection 2.3.9 the title and the enumeration of toc gets stuck together. How can I fix this? In the linked question the space between the number and the title is a little bit bigger.

The font I am using is Kerkis.

Comment: Your question is not related to `tcolorbox` at all

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks for pointing in the right direction that this not related to `tcolorbox`. This https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39971/adjusting-spaces-for-the-toc solved my question .