# table of content bookmark with tcolorbox package

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir, tcolorbox

I am trying to add table of content to the bookmarks while using the `tcolorbox` package, I am using `memoir` class. Following is my MWE.

[image]

```
\documentclass[oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[bookmarks=true]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\chapter{Sample front matter chapter}
\lipsum[1-2]

\newpage

\begin{tcolorbox}[
    breakable,
    enhanced jigsaw,title={\contentsname},fonttitle=\bfseries\Large,
    %   colback=white,% colback=yellow!10!white,
    opacityback=0,
    colframe=red!50!black,before=\par\bigskip\noindent,
    %   interior style={fill overzoom image=goldshade.png,fill image opacity=0.25},
    colbacktitle=red!50!yellow!75!black,
    enlargepage flexible=\baselineskip,pad at break*=3mm,
    %   watermark color=yellow!75!red!25!white,
    %   watermark text={\bfseries\Large \contentsname},
    attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-0.25mm-\tcboxedtitleheight/2,yshifttext=2mm-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},
    boxed title style={enhanced,boxrule=0.5mm,
        frame code={ \path[tcb fill frame] ([xshift=-4mm]frame.west) -- (frame.north west)
            -- (frame.north east) -- ([xshift=4mm]frame.east)
            -- (frame.south east) -- (frame.south west) -- cycle; },
        interior code={ \path[tcb fill interior] ([xshift=-2mm]interior.west)
            -- (interior.north west) -- (interior.north east)
            -- ([xshift=2mm]interior.east) -- (interior.south east) -- (interior.south west)
            -- cycle;}  },
    %   drop fuzzy shadow
    ]
    \makeatletter
    \small
    \@starttoc{toc}
    \makeatother
%       \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{test}
\end{tcolorbox}

\mainmatter
\part{Test Part One}

\chapter{Test Chapter One}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Test Section One}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There you go!

Digging in the `\tableofcontents` macro I found the lines responsible for creating the Table of Contents entry in the table of contents:

```
 \phantomsection% <- Add a placeholder section
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\contentsname}% <- Add the ToC entry to the .toc file
```

Then I just added both right before the `\@starttoc{toc}`.

Also, I took the liberty to add `\thispagestyle{empty}` to the Contents page to remove the title of the previous chapter from the header.

The actual table of contents:
[image]

And naturally, the pdf bookmarks:
[image]

```
\documentclass[oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[bookmarks=true,colorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter

\chapter{Sample front matter chapter}

\lipsum[1-2]

\newpage

\begin{tcolorbox}[
    breakable,
    enhanced jigsaw,title={\contentsname},fonttitle=\bfseries\Large,
    %   colback=white,% colback=yellow!10!white,
    opacityback=0,
    colframe=red!50!black,before=\par\bigskip\noindent,
    %   interior style={fill overzoom image=goldshade.png,fill image opacity=0.25},
    colbacktitle=red!50!yellow!75!black,
    enlargepage flexible=\baselineskip,pad at break*=3mm,
    %   watermark color=yellow!75!red!25!white,
    %   watermark text={\bfseries\Large \contentsname},
    attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-0.25mm-\tcboxedtitleheight/2,yshifttext=2mm-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},
    boxed title style={enhanced,boxrule=0.5mm,
        frame code={ \path[tcb fill frame] ([xshift=-4mm]frame.west) -- (frame.north west)
            -- (frame.north east) -- ([xshift=4mm]frame.east)
            -- (frame.south east) -- (frame.south west) -- cycle; },
        interior code={ \path[tcb fill interior] ([xshift=-2mm]interior.west)
            -- (interior.north west) -- (interior.north east)
            -- ([xshift=2mm]interior.east) -- (interior.south east) -- (interior.south west)
            -- cycle;}  },
    %   drop fuzzy shadow
    ]
    \thispagestyle{empty}% <- SUGGESTION
    \makeatletter
    \small
    % HERE ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓
    \phantomsection
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\contentsname}
    % HERE ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
    \@starttoc{toc}
    \makeatother
\end{tcolorbox}

\mainmatter
\part{Test Part One}

\chapter{Test Chapter One}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Test Section One}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

By the way, nice table of contents :)

Comment: The ToC format is either stolen from the manual of `tcolorbox` or perhaps from here `https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/406158/reproducing-toc-format` ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Ooh... Nice table of contents for you then :) I didn't see your answer before... This is me, always finding the longest path to the solution :P

Comment: I did not invent it. The code in my answer there is taken from the `tcolorbox` manual.

Answer (score 3):

Using `tcolorbox` tools, i.e. defining a special `tocbox` and saying `list inside` and `list type=chapter` does this automatically then.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[bookmarks=true]{hyperref}


\newtcolorbox[list inside=toc,list type=chapter]{tocbox}{%
    breakable,
    enhanced jigsaw,title={\contentsname},fonttitle=\bfseries\Large,
    %   colback=white,% colback=yellow!10!white,
    opacityback=0,
    colframe=red!50!black,before=\par\bigskip\noindent,
    %   interior style={fill overzoom image=goldshade.png,fill image opacity=0.25},
    colbacktitle=red!50!yellow!75!black,
    enlargepage flexible=\baselineskip,pad at break*=3mm,
    %   watermark color=yellow!75!red!25!white,
    %   watermark text={\bfseries\Large \contentsname},
    attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-0.25mm-\tcboxedtitleheight/2,yshifttext=2mm-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},
    boxed title style={enhanced,boxrule=0.5mm,
        frame code={ \path[tcb fill frame] ([xshift=-4mm]frame.west) -- (frame.north west)
            -- (frame.north east) -- ([xshift=4mm]frame.east)
            -- (frame.south east) -- (frame.south west) -- cycle; },
        interior code={ \path[tcb fill interior] ([xshift=-2mm]interior.west)
            -- (interior.north west) -- (interior.north east)
            -- ([xshift=2mm]interior.east) -- (interior.south east) -- (interior.south west)
            -- cycle;}  },
%        list entry=\contentsname
        % drop fuzzy shadow
}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\chapter{Sample front matter chapter}
\lipsum[1-2]

\newpage

\begin{tocbox}
    \makeatletter
    \small
    \@starttoc{toc}
    \makeatother
\end{tocbox}

\mainmatter
\part{Test Part One}

\chapter{Test Chapter One}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Test Section One}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unlike other classes the `memoir` class `\tableofcontents` sets up the ToC and adds its title to the ToC  while `\tableofcontents*` acts like `tablofcontents` in other classes and does not add its title to the ToC. (In retrospect this was probably an unfortunate design decision).

I think that a simple change to your MWE will give you what you want:

Replace the lines:

```
\makeatletter
\small
\@starttoc{toc}
\makeatother
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{test}
\end{tcolorbox}
```

with

```
\small
\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{test} % do you really need this in your final doc?
\end{tcolorbox}
```